# How to make HTML css email in outlook 2016

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, html, microsoft-outlook-2016, css

So, my company uses outlook exchange and now I have to design a HTML Email so it will look like an official company mail with a header with company name/logo and a footer with some information and the middle part for the text.But I have no idea how to do this(no idea at all) and also I have many questions regarding that.Someone please guide me.

My idea is to create sort of a template so that the exchange admin can then use the template and send mails.Is this possible? can he edit the text of the body like bold and stuff or I will have to edit through html css every time for him. I don't want to use any external application again and again ? Is there any free one ?Does it export as oft ? Please help.

Comment: What have you tried? Outlook allows templates and HTML emails and there is documentation on these online, so what research have you done and what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can [create a signature](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-and-add-a-signature-to-messages-8ee5d4f4-68fd-464a-a1c1-0e1c80bb27f2) with your company name/logo in it. Then [export and import it](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/1453-outlook-import-export-signatures.html) to your users' Outlook.